# Запуск внешнего приложения и ожидание его готовности c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Есть некое приложение, которое при запуске рисует форму ввода логина, пароля, (условно: два текстовых поля для ввода текста, кнопка `connect` ).

С помощью win api можно найти дескрипторы этого окна и передать нужные значения полям для ввода текста, нажать клавишу "connect".
Это делается легко, с помощью макросов win api `FindWindow`(ex) и `SendMessage` и др..

**Суть вопроса:**

> Как отследить момент отрисовки формы ввода данных и понять когда моя программа должна вписать логин и пароль? Приложение грузится долго в фоне, минута-три, т.е. время зарпуска меняется. Только после отрисовки окна ввода я могу передать нужные данные.

Самое примитивное решение которое приходит мне в голову - использовать таймер:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "делай раз\n";
    sleep(180000);
    cout << "делай два\n";
    return 0;
}`
```

UPD

```
 #include <iostream> 
 #include <string> 
 #include <vector>
 #include <windows.h> 

 using namespace std; 

 vector<string> WinNames; 

 BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) 
 {
    char str[255]; if (GetWindowText(hwnd, str, 255)) 
    { 
      if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && (!GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER)))
      {
        string s(str); WinNames.push_back(s);
      }
    } return 1;
 }

int main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus"); EnumWindows(&EnumWindowsProc, 0);
  ostream_iterator<string> out(cout,"\n"); 
  copy(WinNames.begin(),WinNames.end(),out); 
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может быть поможет, [очень похож вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107499/how-to-determine-when-spawned-process-is-ready-using-createprocess-and-findw), похоже что [WaitForInputIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687022(VS.85).aspx) делает то что Вам нужно.

Comment: [вот ещё нарыл](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1371836.html) можно найти имя видимого окна среди всех которые запущены. Прикрутить цикл, делать проверку пока не появится нужное название.

Comment: `#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
vector<string> WinNames;
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{char str[255];
if (GetWindowText(hwnd, str, 255)) {
if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && (!GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER))) 
{string s(str);
WinNames.push_back(s);}}
return 1;}
int main()
{setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
 EnumWindows(&EnumWindowsProc, 0);
 ostream_iterator<string> out(cout,"\n");
 copy(WinNames.begin(),WinNames.end(),out);
 system("pause");
 return 0;}`

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin Спасибо, обязательно попробую!

Comment: Проблема решена?? если да то формите коментарий с кодом как ответ